# JSON.parse fails in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome

```
var origtext = Aes.Ctr.decrypt(recentPatientsFile.read().text, 'L0ck it up saf3', 256);
var recentPatientsList = JSON.parse(origtext);
```

while doing an `alert(origtext)`, i get empty data. The JSON.parse(empty data) works fine in other browsers, but in google chrome i get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` . When i remove the JSON.parse(), then everything seems to be fine.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just escape it like this

```
var value = JSON.parse(origtext || "null");
```